# Weird Element Spacing in UniformGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a fairly simple setup so far which looks like this:

[image]

As you can see Number 3 looks perfectly fine. The other two however does not. I have the following code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,5,0" Background="#FFEAEAEA">
        <GroupBox x:Name="playStyleBox" Header="1. Play Style" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <UniformGrid Columns="4">
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxSubtle">Subtle</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxBalanced">Balanced</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxAggressive">Aggressive</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxSupportive">Supportive</CheckBox>
            </UniformGrid>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox x:Name="playStyleSubBox" Header="2. Sub Play Style" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <UniformGrid Columns="3">
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxMelee">Melee</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxRanged">Ranged</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxMagic">Magic</CheckBox>
            </UniformGrid>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox x:Name="alignmentBox" Header="3. Alignment" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <UniformGrid Columns="3">
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxLawfulGood">Lawful Good</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxNeutralGood">Neutral Good</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxChaoticGood">Chaotic Good</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxLawfulNeutral">Lawful Neutral</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxNeutral">Neutral</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxChaoticNeutral">Chaotic Neutral</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxLawfulEvil">Lawful Evil</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxNeutralEvil">Neutral Evil</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxChaoticEvil">Chaotic Evil</CheckBox>
            </UniformGrid>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Width="4" BorderBrush="Red" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <GridSplitter.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
                <Grid>
                    <Button Content="⁞"/>
                    <Rectangle Fill="#FFACACAC"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </GridSplitter.Template>
    </GridSplitter>
</Grid>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am pretty lost as to why this happens to the first two UniformGrid's but not the last one.

Comment: what is the issue exactly? UniformGrids have `Left` horizontal alignment and column width is defined by largest checkbox. in 3 largest checkbox happened to be in the 3rd column, unlike 1 and 2. also in #3 largest checkbox isn't attached to right border because groupBox adds some padding, i think. try add some `Margin` to checkboxes

Comment: @ASh I don't understand. The order of things inside the UniformGrid shouldn't matter should it? It's supposed to be uniform distribution. I've tried to change the order around for the 3rd box and it still works just fine. No weird like mashed up text without proper padding between the boxes and letters. This only happens in the first two boxes. Their setups are identical.

Comment: try write a large string instead of `Lawful Good` (e.g. `Lawful Good Good Good`). after that all columns in #3 will get the same width as the 1st column. in #2 `Ranged` string is the longest, so all #2 columns have the same width as #2 2nd column. all that happen because UniformGrids have `Left` horizontal alignment

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `UniformGrid` create `Columns` of equal size. So, largest control governs the size of the `Column`.
2. Set `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`, and `Margin="10,0,10,0"` in all `GroupBox` .
3. Change number of `Columns` in first `UniformGrid` to 3.